# Remove Pagination in Appearance -> Menus -> Categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I asked this question on WP Stackexchange already but did not get any answers. So let me try here. [Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/299178/remove-pagination-in-appearance-menus-categories)

Is there a way to remove the Pagination in the Wordpress Menu Editor?

I have something like 200 categories in my blog and customising menus seems to be tricky when you have to click through it to find the desired category.

I know there's a plugin that "removes" the pagination for PAGES but I could not find anything to remove the pagination for the CATEGORIES.
I tried to find something in the Wordpress Admin PHP files or even nav-menus.php but did not get lucky.

[Link to Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trbip.png)

Comment: I've looked in the same places and, unfortunately, I don't think it's something you can filter. The numbers look to be hard-coded (to 50 at a time, I think) and almost none of it appears to be filterable.

Comment: My setup doesn't seem to show any pagination.  What version of WordPress are you using and what theme?  Is this when adding a new post?

Comment: @indextwo yes and I was looking for that number but cannot seem to find it anywhere in the php files

Comment: @AndrewSchultz The moment I want to add a post it's fine. there's no pagination. The pagination only displays under Appearance -> Menus -> Categories. I have something like 200 categories and will add about 250 more so this will be very difficult. The search funtion does not even work which makes it even more difficult

Comment: @mad2kx I've coded a solution that will display all the categories in the edit menu screen.  I'm still looking into how you can just adjust the number per page from the default of 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after reading through the source code I found that the number of categories returned in the edit menu section is hardcoded to 50 on line 613 of **\wp-admin\includes\nav-menu.php**

```
// Paginate browsing for large numbers of objects.
    $per_page = 50;
    $pagenum = isset( $_REQUEST[$taxonomy_name . '-tab'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['paged'] ) ? absint( $_REQUEST['paged'] ) : 1;
    $offset = 0 < $pagenum ? $per_page * ( $pagenum - 1 ) : 0;
```

In order to override the default of 50 per page you can set the number to '' to instruct the query to return all categories.  Add the following code to your **functions.php** file.

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'show_all_categories_admin_nav_menu', 10, 2);

function show_all_categories_admin_nav_menu( $args, $taxonomies ) {
    if( reset($taxonomies) === 'category' ) {
        $args['number'] = '';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

If you set the number to blank it still shows the pagination even though it's showing all the categories.

There's also a filter called terms_clauses that exists in which you can remove the SQL LIMIT clause from the query but this didn't seem to have any affect on the query.

```
add_filter('terms_clauses', 'modify_terms_clauses', 10, 3);

function modify_terms_clauses( $clauses, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    if( reset($taxonomies) === 'category' ) {
        $clauses['limits'] = '';
    }

    return $clauses;
}
```

Comment: WOW AWESOME you just saved my life. Thank you so much!

Comment: @mad2kx I don't know about saving your life but I am happy to help :)